# Ionic pro - Build AND Publish to Apple Store

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, cloud

I have a Apple Developer account, BUT **I don't have** a Mac, and I need to do the following with my Ionic project:
Package a native Ionic iOS app AND Publish it to the Apple Store.

I've read about the limitations to compiling and publishing an iOS app in the Apple Store without a Mac, but I am in doubt about the Ionic pro.
There says that Ionic pro can ***'Package native app builds in the cloud'***, but does this mean that I can publish the generated cloud Package from Ionic Pro directly to the Apple Store?

Or will I still need a Mac, or **macincloud.com** service to publish to Apple Store?

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE** (March 31, 2020): Ionic Appflow (previously Ionic Pro) announced 1-click publish to App Stores feature: https://ionicframework.com/blog/announcing-1-click-publish-to-app-stores-from-ionic-appflow/

My experience is that Ionic Pro can do the most of the job but you still need Mac or Mac in cloud at these steps:

- create .p12 Certification file
- upload the .ipa file to the App Store

After you created your Certification file, You can upload it to Ionic Pro -> Settings -> Certificates. You can build .ipa files with proper credentials in cloud. But unfortunately I didn't found another way to upload the .ipa file to App Store, only with Application Loader from Mac.

So I decided to use a pay-as-you-go Mac in cloud account (you pay only for minutes you are logged in) since the time I spend on Mac is very limited (few minutes per App publication).

Anyway, this is a workaround, and I hope that some day there will be an Application Loader service inside the Ionic Pro account.

Comment: Does Apple Legally Allow Public Mac Services in the Cloud on demand?

Comment: AFAIK yes until the service is running on Apple hardware. But the exact answer should be somewhere here: https://www.apple.com/legal/sla/.

Comment: I have just noticed this app which claims that it can upload IPA files from Windows and Linux: http://www.applicationloader.net/
I haven't tried it and not advertising. Just wondering if anyone tried it. Can it be a workaround?