# Ionic 3 compile IPA without mac

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ipa

How do I generate IPA file for my ionic app without using Mac? Is it even possible?

Currently, I just need the generated IPA file; I don't need to deploy the app to the App Store.

I've looked around and these are what I got:

1. Use Ionic package - unfortunately, all links to Ionic package that I got are all dead. So can I assume this service is dead?
2. Use https://build.phonegap.com/ . I know Ionic is based on Phonegap, but does this service actually supports compiling Ionic codes without needing me to modify anything? And even if it can, I read that it needs some sort of certificates to compile to IPA. Is there any way I can get the certificate without a Mac?
3. Use MacInCloud.com. If the options above aren't available, I plan to purchase the pay-as-you-go plan. My question is, do this thing allows me to compile to IPA without me needing any other stuff? Like certificates or whatsoever.

Comment: Check this question for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46697373/ionic-pro-build-and-publish-to-apple-store/48402853

Answer (score 2):

I’m using Ionic Pro (https://ionicframework.com/appflow) to build an IPA and diawi.com to send the app to my clients for testing. To publish app in Apple App Store, I’m using MacInCloud.

Comment: For the ionic Pro, which plan are you using? Can we compile to IPA using the Starter/free plan?

Comment: My current plan is "Starter plan add-on". I think you can do some builds on free account, but it is limited some way.